# Django - apps.py not recognized

Tags: django

Django version 1.11.7

Trying to execute **signals.py** for a post_save execution my code works if i put it in my **models.py** file but i want to separate my signals from my models in **app_1** but seems that even my **apps.py** isn't executed.

The project structure

```
my_project
├──docs
├──src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── apps
│   │   ├── app_1
│   │   │     ├── __init__.py
│   │   │     ├── admin.py
│   │   │     ├── apps.py
│   │   │     ├── signals.py
│   │   │     ├── ...
│   │   │     └── models.py
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── app_x
│   ├── fabfile.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── media
│   │   └── files
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── file_1.html
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── file_x.html
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── app_1
│   │   ├── ....
│   │   └── app_x
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class AppOneConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app_1'

    def ready(self):
        print("test")
        from . import signals
```

**__ init __.py**

```
default_app_config = "apps.app_1.apps.AppOneConfig"
```

And here is the error i have

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'app_1'. Check that 'apps.app_1.apps.AppOneConfig.name' is correct.
```

**settings.py, INSTALLED_APPS**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.app_1'
]
```

Comment: try adding an empty `__init__.py` file in the `apps` directory

Comment: Still same error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'app_1'. Check that 'apps.app_1.apps.AppOneConfig.name' is correct.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**apps.py:**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class AppOneConfig(AppConfig):
            ⬇⬇⬇
    name = 'apps.app_1'

    def ready(self):
        print("test")
        from . import signals
```

**settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.app_1.apps.AppOneConfig' ⬅⬅⬅⬅⬅
     
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't work.
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

Comment: put this `apps.app_1.apps.AppOneConfig`  in your settings.py(INSTALLED_APPS).and remove `default_app_config = "apps.app_1.apps.AppOneConfig"` from `__init__.py`..

Comment: First error came back `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'app_1'. Check that 'apps.app_1.apps.AppOneConfig.name' is correct.`

Comment: ohhh man!! I found your problem..See my updated answer..